# React js y Node js - Error al realizar peticiones con axios en React js

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, cors

Un saludo. Estoy creando una app en la cual utilizo Node js junto a Nodemailer para enviar correos electrónicos y las peticiones las realizo utilizando Axios en React js.

En el backend utilizo "cors", para que se conecte con otros servidores, el error radica en los siguiente, cuando utilizaba de forma local es decir http://localhost:4000 (backend), funcionaba correctamente, pero posteriormente alojé la app de Node js en Heroku, y el enlace lo establecí en axios en lugar del http://localhost:4000, y ahí me indico el problema de políticas de CORS, ahora bien, pienso que como el código del backend es propio, sería más sencillo solucionarlo y me gustaría saber cómo realizarlo.

El código de Node Js:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
        const {name, lastName, email, company, phoneNumber, country, region, docUrl} = req.body;
    
        const htmlEmail = `
            <h3>Cotizaciones Ecuapanama</h3>
            <ul>
                <h1>Asunto: Cotización repuestos</h1>   
                <li>Nombre: ${name}</li>
                <li>Apellido: ${lastName}</li>
                <li>Email: ${email}</li>
                <li>Compañía: ${company}</li>
                <li>Número telefónico: ${phoneNumber}</li>
                <li>País: ${country}</li>
                <li>Provincia/Estado: ${region}</li>
                <h2>Lista de productos</h2>
                <li>Enlace de descarga: ${docUrl}</li>
            </ul>
        `
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: "smtp.gmail.com",
            port: 465,
            auth: {
                user: "correo@gmail.com",
                pass: '************'
            }
        });
        let mailOptions = {
            from: email,
            to: "correo@gmail.com",
            replayTo: email,
            subject: 'Asunto',
            html: htmlEmail
        }
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }
        });
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

El error es el siguiente:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://app-nodejs.herokuapp.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.